# How to parse a character range into a tuple

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators, megaparsec

I want to parse strings like `"0-9"` into `('0', '9')` but I think my two attempts look a bit clumsy.

```hs
numRange :: Parser (Char, Char)
numRange = (,) <$> digitChar <* char '-' <*> digitChar

numRange' :: Parser (Char, Char)
numRange' = liftM2 (,) (digitChar <* char '-') digitChar
```

I kind of expected that there already is an operator that sequences two parsers and returns both results in a tuple. If there is then I can't find it. I'm also having a hard time figuring out the desired signature in order to search on hoogle.

I tried `Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)` based off the signature of `<*` but that only gives unrelated results.

Comment: The function with such signature (`Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)`) is just `liftA2 (,)`. Therefore there is probably need much need to implement such function. The implementations look fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applicative form:

```
numRange = (,) <$> digitChar <* char '-' <*> digitChar
```

is standard.  Anyone familiar with monadic parsers will immediately understand what this does.

The disadvantage of the `liftM2` (or equivalently `liftA2`) form, or of a function with signature:

```
pair :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
pair = liftA2 (,)
```

is that the resulting parser expressions:

```
pair (digitChar <* char '-') digitChar
pair digitChar (char '-' *> digitChar)
```

obscure the fact that the `char '-'` syntax is not actually part of either digit parser.  As a result, I think this is more likely to be confusing than the admittedly ugly applicative syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> I kind of expected that there already is an operator that sequences two parsers and returns both results in a tuple.

There is; it's `liftA2 (,)` as you noticed. However, you *aren't* sequencing two parser, you are sequencing *three* parsers. Even though you can treat this as a "metasequence" of two two-parser sequencing operations, those two operations are *different*:

1. In `digitChar <* char '-'`, you ignore the result of the second parser (and in my opinion, `<*` always looks like a typo for `<*>`).
2. In `... <*> digitChar`, you use both results.

If you don't like using the applicative operators directly, consider using `do` syntax along with the `ApplicativeDo` extension and write

```
numRange :: Parser (Char, Char)
numRange = do
    x <- digitChar
    char '-'
    y <- digitChar
    return (x,y)
```

It's longer, but it's arguably more readable than either of the two using `<*`, which I always think looks like a typo for `<*>`.